# OSError: libmtdev.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, kivy

Somebody know how I can fix this error.
In google search incredibly old information, i don't found answer...
When i close my app, my x-server on Linux start work unbelievably bad. Do not work normal OpenGL 2.0 and OpenGL 3.1, working only XRender without VSync on my KDE neon last version...

log:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/sk2000/.kivy/logs/kivy_21-03-13_69.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/home/sk2000/pro/-pro/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.8 (default, Nov 10 2011, 15:00:00) 
[GCC 10.2.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/home/sk2000/pro/-pro/venv/bin/python"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 0.104.2.dev0, git-Unknown, 2021-03-13 (installed at "/home/sk2000/pro/-pro/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivymd/__init__.py")
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[ERROR  ] [Input       ] MTDev is not supported by your version of linux
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sk2000/pro/-pro/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/input/providers/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    import kivy.input.providers.mtdev
  File "/home/sk2000/pro/-pro/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/input/providers/mtdev.py", line 84, in <module>
    from kivy.lib.mtdev import Device, \
  File "/home/sk2000/pro/-pro/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/lib/mtdev.py", line 29, in <module>
    libmtdev = cdll.LoadLibrary('libmtdev.so.1')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 451, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libmtdev.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'3.0 Mesa 20.3.4 (git-6d8c68603f)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel Open Source Technology Center'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Mesa DRI Intel(R) Iris(R) Plus Graphics 650 (Kaby Lake GT3e) (KBL GT3)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.30'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
main
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event10
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] unable to found provider mtdev
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] fallback on hidinput
[INFO   ] [HIDInput    ] Read event from </dev/input/event10>
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] using <SYNA3602:01 093A:0255 Touchpad >
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <SYNA3602:01 093A:0255 Touchpad > range ABS X position is 0 - 1707
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <SYNA3602:01 093A:0255 Touchpad > range ABS Y position is 0 - 1060
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <SYNA3602:01 093A:0255 Touchpad > range position X is 0 - 1707
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <SYNA3602:01 093A:0255 Touchpad > range position Y is 0 - 1060
[INFO   ] [Loader      ] using a thread pool of 2 workers
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue on Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon, but may be similar for other Linux distributions, like Ubuntu.

It was because I installed PyCharm Community Edition using "Software Manager". It seems ok at very first step, but because it is delivered as flatpack it is not able to access and cooperate with host Linux resources properly. For example you cannot access  Python installed on your machine, you cannot load shared libraries from your machine. That's root cause with MTDev and libmtdev.so.1 false unavaibility.
I also was not able to launch projects outside od PyCharm, because Python venv points to Python binaries which exists only in PyCharm app virtualized environment.

If you are using PyCharm installed by "Software Manager", uninstall it, then download it from official url:

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=linux

Unpack downloaded file into folder you like, then start bin/pycharm.sh everytime you want to launch PyCharm.

PyCharm will launch faster, and you will have no issues with loading shared libraries for MTDev.

Of course if MTDev is not present on your machine, then you have to install it too:

```
sudo apt-get install libmtdev-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the libmtdev-dev package:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install libmtdev-dev`

Comment: i do this, i have this packed version 1.1.5-1.1 in my system

Comment: It does not solve the problem, I also have this error, my system works badly ...